# count number of consecutive dates and group by ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame about user activity that looks like this:

```
| ID     |  week| date    | 
|------- |------| ------- |
| 1      | 1    | 20/07/22| 
| 1      | 2    | 28/07/22| 
| 1      | 2    | 30/07/22| 
| 1      | 3    | 04/08/22| 
| 1      | 3    | 05/08/22| 
| 2      | 2    | 26/07/22| 
| 2      | 2    | 27/07/22| 
| 2      | 3    | 04/08/22|
```

I need to find the sum of consecutive date  for each ID for each week, so the output will look like this- so that for each ID a row per week:

```
| ID     | week | count_consecutive | 
|------- |------| ----------------- |
| 1      | 1    | 0                 | 
| 1      | 2    | 0                 | 
| 1      | 3    | 2                 | 
| 2      | 2    | 2                 | 
| 2      | 3    | 0                 |
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post the code

Comment: Are you sure that the ouput should be what you gave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `apply` a custom function:

```
# You can replace .eq(pd.Timedelta(days=1)) by .eq('1D'), enhanced by @mozway
consecutive_days = lambda x: x.diff().eq(pd.Timedelta(days=1)).sum() + 1

out = (df.groupby(['ID', 'week'])['date']
         .apply(consecutive_days)
         .where(lambda x: x > 1, other=0)
         .rename('count_consecutive').reset_index())

print(out)

# Output
   ID  week  count_consecutive
0   1     1                  0
1   1     2                  0
2   1     3                  2
3   2     2                  2
4   2     3                  0
```

The problem here is the logic you used: 0 if there is no consecutive day but 2 if there one consecutive day. So in the result, it cannot have 1.

Comment: Thank you. I don't see a problem with my logic- there isn't a thing as 1 consecutive day, it's either no consecutive at all, or at least 2.

Comment: You can also use a string for timedelta comparisons `.eq('1D')`

Comment: Oh! I don't know about that!!!